# Does a rank 1 CAT(0) space with a proper cocompact group action contain a zero width axis?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, non-positive-curvature

A geodesic in a proper CAT(0) space is said to be rank 1 if it does not bound a flat half-plane and zero-width if it does not bound a flat strip of any width.
Let $X$ be a geodesically complete CAT(0) space that contains a rank 1 geodesic. Assume it admits a properly discontinuous cocompact action by a group $G$.

Under these conditions we know:

1. $X$ contains a rank 1 geodesic which is an axis of an isometry in $G$ ([Link, Lemma 4.2]
   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00402.pdf).
2. $X$ contains  zero-width geodesic ([Ricks, Theorem 2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3921).

My question: Must $X$ necessarily contain a *zero-width* geodesic which is the axis of some isometry in $G$?

Comment: Maybe this is built in to your definition, but do you want to assume that $X$ is irreducible? Otherwise I think you can just take a product with an interval to get a counterexample (and to Ricks' theorem).

Comment: I believe this would not be geodesically complete--not all geodesic segments would be extendible to infinity

Comment: Good point, thanks, I assumed I was missing something.

Comment: The question has a positive answer at least for CAT(0) cube complexes. Caprace and Sageev constructed isometries skewering pairs of *strongly separated* hyperplanes, and the axis of such an isometry must have zero width.